# Getting vnet integration infos from a service plan

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

**CONTEXT**

Whe deploy an Azure Function with a vnet integration with a code like this:

```
$properties = @{
            subnetResourceId = $subnet.Id
        }

$vNetParams = @{
                ResourceName      = "$webapp/VirtualNetwork"
                Location          = $Location
                ResourceGroupName = $ResourceGroupName
                ResourceType      = "Microsoft.Web/sites/networkConfig"
                PropertyObject    = $properties
}

$result = New-AzResource @vNetParams -Force
```

This works fine.

The project get $subnet by looking an available subnet into a spoke VNET.
So I don't want to run the previous code when a VNET integration already exists.

**WHAT I NEED**

A way to know if a Function has already a VNET integration

**WHAT I TESTED**

```
Get-AzFunctionApp  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $webapp 

Get-AzFunctionAppPlan -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $servicePlan 

Get-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $servicePlan
```

Returns no vnet informations

```
Get-AzResource doesn't work with this resource: "$webapp/VirtualNetwork"  (not found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a function app has already a vnet integration, just use the command below.

```
$VnetName = (Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName <groupname> -Name <functionappname>).SiteConfig.VnetName
if($VnetName){
    Write-Output "already intergration"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to figure this in portal.

1. Navigate to Azure portal
2. Select the corresponding Web App or Function App
3. Navigate to "Diagnose and solve problems" and search for "VNet Integration Information"
4. This will load a blade, which will have details of the Web App in that App Service Plan

This is what the UI looks like
[image: VNet Integration Information]